# EnumOptionIDs for testResult not working correctly?

Tags: c#, polarion

I am trying to create a testRun, whenever I post my results in only the ones that were marked "passed" works. Any Post that are marked as "failed" or "failed with no defect" do not show up correctly in the test run.

This is all using :

`con.TestManegment.addTestRecords(testRun.uri, test.uri, testResult (The problem), text, authoruri, today);`

As I understand it, polarion is VERY picky about the strings it lets through. However I have done very extensive research and cannot find valid values for this. All that I can get to work are "passed" and "blocked".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Go to Administration>Testing>Test Results
The 'ID' of the Results mentioned in this enumeration file are the valid values for your method.
Look for the 'ID' of the "failed with no defect" result.